# How right load data from module, which is not located near?

Tags: python, import, upload, loaddata

For example, I have next tree:

[image]

I use `app.py` and I need to  upload data in script. My data is situated in `data_folder`.
I just want use script `load.py` to upload data without set any paths to `app.py`

For example, `load.py` has  function `load_data('/data_folder/data.json')`
How I can use only call of  this function from `load.py` in `app.py` ?

Now, I am calling `app.py' and predictably it throws error` No such file o directory data_folder/data.json`, because script calls from` app.py` which has not this folder near.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the argument to `load_data('/data_folder/data.json')` with

```
from pathlib import Path
load_data(f'{Path(__file__).parent}/data_folder/data.json')
```

this will allow the path to resolve relative to `load.py`.